# Sql Server 2016 ctp3 R configuration error

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am getting error when try to execute post installation scripts to configure R. I installed sql server 2016 ctp3 as named instance.

Running below command :

```
“%programfiles%\RRO\RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\RegisterRExt” /install /instance:myserver\sql2016
```

Error :
**Connecting to SQL server...
Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
 Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Err
or Locating Server/Instance Specified)
Failed to complete the operation successfully.**

Tried using Powershell too but same error. I am able to connect to same named instance through sqlcmd or directly fine but above command always fail with same error. I am admin on the box.
Already checked firewall rules and added all ports being used by new instance. No luck though.

Thanks for help.
NJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the instance name parameter, you need to specify only the SQL instance name "SQL2016" without the machine name.